# como mostrar el contenido de una consulta mysql en php

Tags: php, html, mysql, mysqli

quiero pedir su ayuda, ya que he estado intentando imprimir el resultado de la siguiente consulta que en php la expreso de la siguiente manera

```
$consulta_horas = "SELECT SEC_TO_TIME( SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(fin,inicio))) ) FROM bitacoras_sistemas WHERE id = '".$user."' 
        AND inicio BETWEEN '".$inicio."' AND '".$fin."'
        AND fin BETWEEN '".$inicio."' AND '".$fin."'";
$resultado_horas = mysqli_query($conexion, $consulta_horas);
print_r ($resultado_horas);
```

La consulta funciona correctamente y la ejecuto, a la hora de imprimir el contenido de la variable `$resultado_horas` me sale lo siguiente:

---

```
mysqli_result Object
(
    [current_field] => 0
    [field_count] => 1
    [lengths] => 
    [num_rows] => 1
    [type] => 0
)
```

y cuando ejecuto la consulta en la base de datos me da el resultado que busco
como se muestra en la siguiente imagen:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

no se como hacer para que este resultado se me muestre en un label de html, alguien puede ayudarme se lo agradeceria mucho.

Answer (score 1):

Primer punto ponle un alias a la columna que calculas, es decir tu tienes esto

```
SEC_TO_TIME( SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(fin,inicio))) )
```

Ponle por ejemplo esto `Diferencia` para poder recuperar dicho valor

```
SEC_TO_TIME( SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(fin,inicio))) ) AS Diferencia
```

Posterior, como es un array lo que te devuelve, recorrelo con un `foreach` así

```
foreach($resultado_horas as $hora){
    echo $hora["Diferencia"];
}
```

Donde como notas accedo al nombre o alias que le pusimos al calculo que estas haciendo en tu query

Finalmente tu código debería ser este

```
$consulta_horas = "SELECT SEC_TO_TIME( SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(fin,inicio))) ) AS Diferencia FROM bitacoras_sistemas WHERE id = '".$user."' 
        AND inicio BETWEEN '".$inicio."' AND '".$fin."'
        AND fin BETWEEN '".$inicio."' AND '".$fin."'";
$resultado_horas = mysqli_query($conexion, $consulta_horas);


foreach($resultado_horas as $hora){
    echo $hora["Diferencia"];
}
```

Ahora para meter ese resultado en una `label` no deberás hacer algo mas que esto

```
echo "<label>".$hora["Hora"]."</label>";
```

Comment: Hola, acabo de intentar esto que me mencionas pero al final no me imprime nada en el label no se si estoy haciendo algo mal, te pongo el codigo que acabo de modificar tomando tu aporte`$consulta_horas = "SELECT SEC_TO_TIME( SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(fin,inicio))) ) AS total FROM bitacoras_sistemas WHERE id = '".$user."' 
  AND inicio BETWEEN '".$inicio."' AND '".$fin."'
  AND fin BETWEEN '".$inicio."' AND '".$fin."'";
 $resultado_horas = mysqli_query($conexion, $consulta_horas);`
 `foreach($resultado_horas as $hora){
    echo $hora["total"];
}` `echo "<label>".$hora["total"]."</label>";`

Comment: Claro, si encuentras algo te agradeceria si me ayudas @Aprendiz

Comment: pues si pongo el codigo tal cual, no me imprime nada, me pone una pagina en blanco, y en el label solo me pone la cadena que escribí para identificarlo `echo "<label> El total es: ".$hora["total"]."</label>";` @Aprendiz

Comment: Me devuelve esto `array (size=1)
  'total' => null`